# Extracting values from a queue in javascript

Tags: javascript

I have created a queue in java script which is stored in the following manner

```
function MyType(coords, val) {
  this.coords = coords;
  this.val = val;
}

function Couple(x, y) {


  this.x = x;
  this.y = y ;
}

var queue =  [];
villianXPos = 4;
villianYPos = 4;
queue.push(new MyType(new Couple(villianXPos,villianYPos, 0)));
```

Now I want to extract the coordinates and the  val in separate variables

when I do

```
 var element = queue.shift();
```

The element is getting the entire value 4,4,0

Is it possible to get only 4,4 in my element variable and 0 in another variable ?

Comment: u can assign the array a values to each var as u need..

Comment: looking at `var queue =  [ [[[10,20],0]] ];` it seems you expect `queue.push` will put in `[[villanXPos, villanYPos], 0]` ?

Comment: @mzzzzb well atleast alert(element) is showing 10,20,0 . so it seems thats what its doing. u can ignore villianXPos,villianYPos for now

Comment: `new Couple(villianXPos,villianYPos, 0)`, `0` is never used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming

```
queue.push(new MyType(new Couple(villianXPos,villianYPos, 0)));
```

should actually be

```
queue.push(new MyType(new Couple(villianXPos,villianYPos), 0));
```

then

```
function MyType(coords, val) {
  this.coords = coords;
  this.val = val;
}

function Couple(x, y) {
  this.x = x;
  this.y = y ;
}

var queue =  [];
villianXPos = 4;
villianYPos = 4;
queue.push(new MyType(new Couple(villianXPos,villianYPos), 0)); 

var meh = queue.shift();
console.log(meh.coords);
//yields Couple {x: 4, y: 4} 
console.log(meh.coords.x);
//yields 4
console.log(meh.val);
//yields 0
console.log(queue);
//yields the remainder of the queue, in this case empty array []
```

However, it is good practice to use getter/setter for this kind of object access

Comment: thks ...I got the mistake with 

queue.push(new MyType(new Couple(villianXPos,villianYPos, 0)));